# Loopback Module login error

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I have took a errored loopback project for correction in which has a module let it be **Provider** it has a function **Provider/Login**  comes with POST method... this is the error stated by the customer that if he gives gor example {"email":"xxx@gmail.com","password":"123456"} .
It's prompting with the error given below :

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "login failed",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "code": "LOGIN_FAILED"
  }
}
```

I cant find what the Issue is though i have checked most of the code. I'm new to LOOPBACK so any kind help is welcomed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It shows that you are putting `invalid credentials`, `401 statusCode` is for `Unauthorized`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smmith, It is clearly showing that error code is 401 which means unauthorize. which means the credentials are wrong.

Please create a user with these credentials before putting the login call.

If your Provider belongs to a USER class, than you can use the create call of provider to create the user first.

Comment: I'm facing another issue, if i go to that model Provider and call a GET method it shows :